# Работа с массивами и строками

Tags: c#, массивы

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\uploads\input.txt"))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        list.Add(line);                
    }
}
```

Таким образом получаю строку вида `login;password` . Думаю отделить логины от паролей на два разных массива и со вторым - паролями - провести нужные операции(хэширование, к примеру), а потом собрать обратно чтобы пары `логин;пароль` соответсвовали. 
Насколько это разумный подход к решению задачи?

**UPD:** Суть задачи: Есть входной файл с парами логин-пароль, необходимо получить выходной файл с парами логин-пароль, но пароли нужно обработать отдельной независимой функцией.

Comment: А зачем разбирать, собирать, а не работать сразу с парой логин/пароль - какой вы видите в этом смысл? Задайтесь этим вопросом и вы поймете насколько это разумно..., ну или сможете переформулировать свой вопрос, сейчас он малосодержателен.

Comment: >Насколько это разумный подход к решению задачи?
Какой задачи?

Comment: К UPD, ну так и обработайте пару логин/пароль, какой вы видите смысл их разделять?

Comment: вам нужно получить на выходе файл с парами `логин;хэш_пароля`. Если нет - то я не понял вопрос :(

Comment: @PashaPash Именно это и нужно.

Comment: А почему не используете как ключ-значение какой-то меп?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вполне разумный подход. Но я бы на вашем месте не заморачивался с ручной работой через `StreamReader` - есть отличные методы класса `File` для чтения строк как `IEnumerable<string>` и записи `IEnumerable<string>` обратно в файл:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var outputLines =
        File.ReadLines(@"c:\temp\in.txt")
        .Where(l => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(l))
        .Select(l => l.Split(';'))
        .Select(t => String.Format("{0}:{1}", t[0], HashPassword(t[1])));
    File.WriteAllLines(@"c:\temp\out.txt", outputLines);
}

private static string HashPassword(string pass)
{
    return new String(pass.Reverse().ToArray());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Я бы сделал что-то подобное:

```
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      // Если файл с логинами и паролями небольшой:
      var lines = File.ReadAllLines("file").Select(l => new Line(l)).ToList();
      lines.ForEach(l => l.CalculateHash());
      var resultLines = lines.Select(l => string.Format("{0};{1}", l.Login, l.Hash)).ToList();
      File.WriteAllLines("outputFile", resultLines);

      // Иначе, надо бы работать по очереди с каждой строкой:
      foreach (var line in File.ReadLines("file"))
      {
        var parsed = new Line(line);
        parsed.CalculateHash();
        File.AppendAllText("outputFile", string.Format("{0};{1}", parsed.Login, parsed.Hash));
      }
    }
  }

  public class Line
  {
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Hash { get; set; }

    public void CalculateHash()
    {
      // Тут нужный код вычисления.
      this.Hash = this.Password.GetHashCode().ToString();
    }

    public Line(string input)
    {
      var s = input.Split(';');
      if (s.Length == 2)
      {
        this.Login = s[0];
        this.Password = s[1];
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Ну, всё просто.

Список строк из входного файла получаем при помощи `File.ReadLines`. Разбиваем на логин и пароль через `string.Split`. Обрабатываем как получится, склеиваем назад и записываем в файл через `File.WriteAllLines`. Используем LINQ, чтобы не грузить память.

Получаем:

```
var srcLines = File.ReadLines("input.txt");
var inputData = srcLines.Select(l => l.Split(new[] { ';' }, 2)
                        .Select(parts => new { login = parts[0], password = parts[1] };
var processedData = inputData.Select(lp => new
                                           {
                                               lp.login,
                                               hash = ComputeHash(lp.password)
                                           });
var outLines = processedData.Select(lh => $"{lh.login};{lh.hash}");
File.WriteAllLines("output.txt", outLines);
```

Или то же вместе:

```
File.WriteAllLines(
    "output.txt",
    File.ReadLines("input.txt")
        .Select(l => l.Split(new[] { ';' }, 2))
        .Select(parts => new { login = parts[0], password = parts[1] })
        .Select(lp => new { lp.login, hash = ComputeHash(lp.password) })
        .Select(lh => $"{lh.login};{lh.hash}"));
```

Если результат хеширования — набор байт, а не строка, нужно ещё применить `BitConverter.ToString(hash)`.